# Response.Clear() equivalent in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpresponse

I'm very new to MVC. How do I perform a `Response.Clear()` from within an MVC3 aspx page?

I have tried:

```
Response.Clear();

ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
```

Neither of them seem to function at all, in that any HTML content before the statements remain in the output. The only thing that seems to work is `Response.Close()`, but of course that doesn't allow me to output anything afterwards.

The reason for wanting this simply a testing/debugging exercise - I just want to be able to clear the buffered output, from inline code in the aspx page, and output something else afterwards. Similar to what one could do with web forms.

Note, I don't want to perform this within the controller, as it means re-compiling every time I make a change, as well as losing session state. The point of this is to fiddle within the aspx page to avoid re-compiling each time.

Comment: are you putting Response.Clear(); in view or controller??

Comment: Do you want to call the `Clear()` method before the action is executed, afterwards or while it is being rendered?

Comment: @Serv, preferably both, if possible. But mostly before the action.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from your comment, that you want to mess with your code before an Action is executed and afterwards, the most ideal solution is to use custom ActionFilters:

```
public interface IActionFilter
{
    void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext);
    void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext);
}
```

`OnActionExecuting` is used to execute code before your Controller action is called, while `OnActionExecuted` is used after the action method has done its job.

So you hook up a custom filter like this:

```
public class MyCustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       //put your custom response and shenanigans here
       ...
       return;
   }
}
```

After this you can decorate your controller method with this filter:

```
[MyCustomFilter]
public ActionResult ListSomething()
{
   /* magic happens here */
}
```

There's a lot you can achieve here, but I suggest some further reading into this:

- http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/b11a280114-Understanding-ASP.NET-MVC-Filters-and-Attributes.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232768.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(vs.98).aspx

Sidenote: If this is just for learning and debugging purposes, I'd take a look at newer mvc versions (4, 5).

Comment: Thanks very much, that's a really interesting approach to look into. However I assume it means recompiling the project every time I make a change to the output? I'm learning in order to work with an existing project which is quite large, so recompiling really slows things down, and also loses session state, making it even more difficult to fiddle. I'm surprised there isn't an easy way to "hack around" in MVC3.

Comment: Is there any code which can be placed in the aspx file itself, to avoid recompiling after every change?

Comment: I honestly have never worked with mvc + aspx. At the very first contact I immedieatly switched to Razer; that being said, everything I test and debug I do with UnitTests in MVC. Html and css fiddeling doesnt need recompiling at all. This has worked out pretty well for me and I did not need some hacking and work around with response manipulation up until now

Answer (score 0):

In stead of focussing on `Response`, perhaps you should focus on what you wish to return in your controller method.

If you wish to return a full rendered `View`

```
return View("myView");
```

If you wish to return a `PartialView`

```
return PartialView("myPartialView");
```

If you wish to return a FileStream

```
return File(myBytes, "filename.ext");
```

If you wish to return a `Json` string,

```
return Json(myObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. I've edited the question to explain why I'm after that approach, to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: I get that.. but you have to understand that MVC is very different from normal forms. In the ideal situation you do not need to do anything with the Response object.

Comment: I realise that is the ideal solution. This sort of exercise is not meant to be ideal, it's meant to be temporary, quick and expedient.

Comment: I understand.. MVC does things differently though than the classic ASP.NET though and it uses the Response to do its magic. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
```

Istead of :

```
ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
```

Comment: Flush forces the buffered output to the browser, so I don't see how that will help.